# Getting an error while following the rust book

Tags: rust

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn one_result() {
        let query = "duct";
        let contents = "\
Rust:
safe, fast, productive.
Pick three.";

        assert_eq!(vec!["safe, fast, productive."], search(query, contents));
    }
}

pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    vec![]
}

pub struct Config {
    pub query: String,
    pub filename: String,
}
impl Config {
    pub fn new(args: &[String]) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        if args.len() < 3 {
            return Err("not enough arguments");
        }
        let query = args[1].clone();
        let filename = args[2].clone();

        Ok(Config { query, filename })
     }
}
pub fn run(config: Config) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string(config.filename)?;

    println!("{}",contents);

    Ok(())
}
```

this is my lib.rs

```
use std::{env, process};
use minigrep::Config;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    
    let config = Config::new(&args).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        println!("Problem parsing arguments: {}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    });
    
    //println!("Searching for {}", config.query);
    //println!("In file {}", config.filename);

    if let Err(e) = minigrep::run(config) {
        println!("Application error: {}", e);

        process::exit(1);
    }
    
}
```

This is my main.rs

My problem: I'm following the rust book building the minigrep app.  It's a little difficult to know if I have the code exactly right because of the snips. I'm new to rust and can't figure out why in my lib.rs I'm getting an error that says 'query' and 'contents' are unused variables.  I'm trying to run a test that purposely fails following the instructions in the rust book.

Comment: *"'query' and 'contents' are unused variables"* - This is a warning, but not an error.

Comment: But they didn't have the same warning in the book example.  Anything I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"'query' and 'contents' are unused variables"* - This is a warning, but not an error.

The warning is caused by the `search` function, in which the parameter `query` and `contents` are not used:

> ```rust
> pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
>    vec![]
> }
> ```

You have to continue in the book. Once the main part of the `search` function is filled with the final code, the warnings will go away:

> ```rust
> pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
>    let mut results = Vec::new();
>    for line in contents.lines() {
>        if line.contains(query) {
>            results.push(line);
>        }
>    }
>    results
> }
> ```

Comment: I tried continuing on in the book and I was still getting warnings with the test after we built out the search function.  I figured it was related to the initial warning.  So far in the book when there is supposed to be an error/warning they point it out.  This time there was nothing so i'm assuming this is supposed to work with no warnings.  Ultimately, when I continue on my test results aren't consistent with the book.

Comment: @mike Do you understand my answer? It is obvious that the parameters are not used, isn't it? I can only point out the obvious problem in the code of your question. Since you've read the book this far, you should be able to confirm this.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.  I think when I continued earlier I made a mistake.  The test works after I went ahead in the book again.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: @mike I've found the missing code for you.